# rename file in one folder and copy a file to that folder after

Tags: batch-file, installation, copy

I'm a newbie, so bear with me...

I'm trying to create a batch file Which does the following

1. Rename setup.exe in `src\Research.Setup\Release` to
   `install.exe`.

   ```
   CD src\Research.Setup\Release
   ren "setup.exe" "install.exe"
   ```
2. Then copy another file `setup.exe` from `src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release` to "src\Research.Setup\Release".

   ```
   Copy "src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release\setup.exe"
   "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe"
   ```

The copy here is not working, please can someone help with that.

I cannot get the batch file to work.. any help will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current working directory gets changed in step 1.

Easy change to make step 1 not use `CD`. Instead it could be `move src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe src\Research.Setup\Release\install.exe`

Otherwise, after step 1, change back to the directory that you want to run step 2 from.

**Example**

```
ren "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe" "install.exe"
copy "src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release\setup.exe" "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe"
```

or

```
pushd "src\Research.Setup\Release"
ren "setup.exe" "install.exe"
popd
copy "src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release\setup.exe" "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe"
```

or

```
move "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe" "src\Research.Setup\Release\install.exe"
copy "src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release\setup.exe" "src\Research.Setup\Release\setup.exe"
```

Comment: i am not trying to move the file.. just copy it. Move will remove the file from orignal location. Also i want to copy from 2 different locations : "src\Research.SetupWrapper\Release" and "src\Research.Setup\Release"

Comment: @user175084  This answer will solve your issue,  1. Either use `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd` or 2. Remove the `cd` command all together.   The move recommendation is just an alternative to the rename.